# Remove line in the graph - highcharts

Tags: graphics, highcharts

I'm not finding the Highcharts API http://api.highcharts.com/. How do I remove these two lines are off the chart.

http://www.likecomunicacao.com.br/clientes/playtv/grafico/grafico2.html

Does anyone know?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to turn off the [dataLabels](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.pie.dataLabels.enabled) for the Pie. They are on by default.

```
plotOptions: {
    pie: {
        innerSize: '70%',
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: false
        }
    },
    series: {
        enableMouseTracking: false,

    }
},
```